# React Website gives blank page on IOS Safari

Tags: ios, reactjs, build, safari, netlify

I created a single page website with React. While it works fine on Android and Windows devices, I get a white page error on IOS-based devices. I have tried many solutions.
I don't get console error for Safari (latest version) for Windows either.
Here for live : https://fitbodyclub.netlify.app/
It has many code you may look at it here : https://github.com/kececibora/FitBodyClub-Website

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fitclub",
  "homepage": "https://fitbodyclub.netlify.app/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.3.15",
    "number-counter": "^1.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.12.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried :
1 - `"start_url": ".",`  // in manifest.json
2 - delete iframe from files
3- `"homepage": ".",` // added to package.json
4- ``` "start_url": "``https://fitbodyclub.netlify.app/``", ``` // added in manifest.json
5-`"start": "yarn run start:tw & sleep 1 && yarn run start:cra",`  // added in package.json
6- `<iframe allow="fullscreen"`  // added allow to iframe
7-
I started to rebuild it. I found the file gives that problem :

```
  // import Header from "./Header/Header";
import "./Hero.css";
import hero_image from "../assets/hero_image.png";
import hero_image_back from "../assets/hero_image_back.png";
import Heart from "../assets/heart.png";
import Calories from "../assets/calories.png";

const transition = { type: "spring", duration: 3 };
const mobile = window.innerWidth <= 768 ? true : false;

function Hero() {
  return (
    <div className="hero" id="home">
      <div className="blur hero-blur"></div>
      <div className="left-h">
        {/* <Header /> */}
        {/* slogan */}
        <div className="slogan">
          <div
            initial={{ left: mobile ? "165px" : "238px" }}
            whileInView={{ left: "8px" }}
            transition={{ ...transition, type: "tween" }}
          ></div>
          <span>Sporun Kalbi burada atıyor </span>
        </div>
        {/* Büyük Slogan */}
        <div className="hero-text">
          <div>
            <span className="bosluk-text">Hayalinizdeki </span>
            <span>Vücuda</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>Kavuşma Zamanı</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              Burada sizlere hayalinizdeki vücuda kavuşmanıza yardım ediyoruz.
              Sen de yapabilirsin!
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* Figürler */}
        <div className="figures">
          <div>
            <span>+500</span>
            <span>metrekare</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>+2500</span>
            <span>Üyelik</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>+250</span>
            <span>Ekipman</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*Butonlar  */}
        <div className="hero-buttons">
          <button className="btn">Katıl Bize</button>
          <button className="btn">Daha Fazlası</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="right-h">
        <button className="btn">Üye Girişi</button>
        <div
          initial={{ right: "-1rem" }}
          whileInView={{ right: "4rem" }}
          transition={transition}
          className="heart-rate"
        >
          <img src={Heart} alt="" />
          <span>Heart Rate</span>
          <span>116bpm</span>
        </div>
        {/* Hero images */}
        <img src={hero_image} alt="" className="hero-image" id="hero_image" />
        <img
          initial={{ right: "11rem" }}
          whileInView={{ right: "20rem" }}
          transition={transition}
          src={hero_image_back}
          alt=""
          className="hero-image-back"
          id="hero_image_back"
        />
        {/* Kalori */}
        <div
          initial={{ right: "37rem" }}
          whileInView={{ right: "28rem" }}
          transition={transition}
          className="calories"
        >
          <img src={Calories} alt="" />
          <div>
            <span>Kalori</span>
            <span>220 kcal</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

I started to rebuild it. I found the file gives that problem :

Comment: So usually this happens because that particular browser doesn't support a specific feature in your code. However, what that thing is could be one of a whole bunch of possibilities. Only way is to start commenting thing out to narrow it down. If you Google it, people get this same exact issue when using native `fetch`, or when using fat arrow functions in their src, or using certain 3rd party libs, or a whole bunch of other things. Rendering the minimal amount possible and slowly adding more should let you see which part specifically causes the error, then once identified you can go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part by part i builded so, a css element **mix-blend-mode** causes problem.

```
.App{mix-blend-mode: overlay;}
```